# Bluetooth socket doesn't work Android

Tags: android, sockets, bluetooth

I am trying to make an app that send audio over Bluetooth socket .So far I reached at the point that i get the paired devices and start the connect thread (client) but it dose not work probably i will ((right now i am just trying to send a text )).
this my code :

```
 public class MainActivity extends Activity implements AdapterView.OnItemClickListener {



String tag="debuger";
ArrayAdapter<String> listAdapter;
Button connectNew;
ListView listView;
BluetoothAdapter btAdapter;
ArrayList<BluetoothDevice> devices;
Set<BluetoothDevice> deviceArray;
IntentFilter filter;
BroadcastReceiver receiver;
ArrayList<String> pairedDevices;

public static final UUID MY_UUID=UUID.fromString("00001101-0000-1000-8000-00805FB34FB");
protected static final int SUCCESS_CONNECT=0;
protected static final int MESSAGE_READ=1;
       Handler mhandler=new Handler(){

    @Override
    public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
        super.handleMessage(msg);
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "entreing the handler", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        switch (msg.what){
   @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    init();
    getpairedDevices();



}

private void startDiscovery() {

    btAdapter.cancelDiscovery();
    btAdapter.startDiscovery();
}



private void init(){

    devices=new ArrayList<BluetoothDevice>();
    btAdapter=BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();
    filter=new IntentFilter(BluetoothDevice.ACTION_FOUND);
    receiver=new BroadcastReceiver() {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            String action=intent.getAction();

            if (BluetoothDevice.ACTION_FOUND.equals(action)){

                BluetoothDevice device=intent.getParcelableExtra(BluetoothDevice.EXTRA_DEVICE);
                devices.add(device);
                String s="";
                for (int a=0;a<pairedDevices.size();a++){

                    if(device.getName().equals(pairedDevices.get(a))){


                        //apend

                        s="(Paired)";
                        break;
                    }



                }

                listAdapter.add(device.getName()+"\n"+s+device.getAddress());

            } if(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_DISCOVERY_STARTED.equals(action));{

               // Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"start",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            }

             if(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_STATE_CHANGED.equals(action)){
              //  Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"state",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
             }

             if(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_DISCOVERY_FINISHED.equals(action)){
                 //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"finish",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();



             }
        }
    };  registerReceiver(receiver,filter);
    filter=new IntentFilter(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_DISCOVERY_STARTED);
    registerReceiver(receiver,filter);

    filter=new IntentFilter(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_DISCOVERY_FINISHED);
    registerReceiver(receiver,filter);

    filter=new IntentFilter(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_STATE_CHANGED);
    registerReceiver(receiver,filter);

    connectNew=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button);
    listView=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.listView);
    listAdapter=new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,0);
    listView.setAdapter(listAdapter);
    pairedDevices=new ArrayList<String>();


    listView.setOnItemClickListener(this);



}
@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    unregisterReceiver(receiver);
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if(resultCode == RESULT_CANCELED){
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Bluetooth must be enabled to continue", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        finish();
    }
}

private void getpairedDevices(){

    deviceArray=btAdapter.getBondedDevices();
    if(deviceArray.size()>0){

        for(BluetoothDevice device:deviceArray){

            pairedDevices.add(device.getName());



        }



    }
}

public void TurnOn(View view) {


    btAdapter.enable();




}


@Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2, long arg3) {

   //

    if (btAdapter.isDiscovering()){


        btAdapter.cancelDiscovery();

    }
    if (listAdapter.getItem(arg2).contains("Paired")){

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    unregisterReceiver(receiver);
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if(resultCode == RESULT_CANCELED){
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Bluetooth must be enabled to continue", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        finish();
    }
}

private void getpairedDevices(){

    deviceArray=btAdapter.getBondedDevices();
    if(deviceArray.size()>0){

        for(BluetoothDevice device:deviceArray){

            pairedDevices.add(device.getName());



        }



    }
}

public void TurnOn(View view) {


    btAdapter.enable();




}


@Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2, long arg3) {

   //

    if (btAdapter.isDiscovering()){


        btAdapter.cancelDiscovery();

    }
    if (listAdapter.getItem(arg2).contains("Paired")){




            case SUCCESS_CONNECT:

                String s="hothyfa its a success";
                ConnectedThread connectedThread=new ConnectedThread((BluetoothSocket)msg.obj);
                connectedThread.write(s.getBytes());
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Succcssss",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                break;
            case MESSAGE_READ:
                byte[] readbuf=(byte[])msg.obj;
                String s2=new String(readbuf);
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),s2,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();


                break;
        }
    }
};
                @Override
                    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    init();
    getpairedDevices();



}

private void startDiscovery() {

    btAdapter.cancelDiscovery();
    btAdapter.startDiscovery();
}



private void init(){

    devices=new ArrayList<BluetoothDevice>();
    btAdapter=BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();
    filter=new IntentFilter(BluetoothDevice.ACTION_FOUND);
    receiver=new BroadcastReceiver() {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            String action=intent.getAction();

            if (BluetoothDevice.ACTION_FOUND.equals(action)){

                BluetoothDevice device=intent.getParcelableExtra(BluetoothDevice.EXTRA_DEVICE);
                devices.add(device);
                String s="";
                for (int a=0;a<pairedDevices.size();a++){

                    if(device.getName().equals(pairedDevices.get(a))){


                        //apend

                        s="(Paired)";
                        break;
                    }



                }

                listAdapter.add(device.getName()+"\n"+s+device.getAddress());

            }
             if(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_DISCOVERY_STARTED.equals(action));{

               // Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"start",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            }

             if(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_STATE_CHANGED.equals(action)){
              //  Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"state",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
             }

             if(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_DISCOVERY_FINISHED.equals(action)){
                 //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"finish",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();



             }
        }
    };

    registerReceiver(receiver,filter);
    filter=new IntentFilter(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_DISCOVERY_STARTED);
    registerReceiver(receiver,filter);

    filter=new IntentFilter(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_DISCOVERY_FINISHED);
    registerReceiver(receiver,filter);

    filter=new IntentFilter(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_STATE_CHANGED);
    registerReceiver(receiver,filter);

    connectNew=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button);
    listView=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.listView);
    listAdapter=new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,0);
    listView.setAdapter(listAdapter);
    pairedDevices=new ArrayList<String>();


    listView.setOnItemClickListener(this);



}
                 @Override
                 protected void onPause() {
                super.onPause();
                 unregisterReceiver(receiver);
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if(resultCode == RESULT_CANCELED){
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Bluetooth must be enabled to continue", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        finish();
    }
}

private void getpairedDevices(){

    deviceArray=btAdapter.getBondedDevices();
    if(deviceArray.size()>0){

        for(BluetoothDevice device:deviceArray){

            pairedDevices.add(device.getName());



        }



    }
}

public void TurnOn(View view) {


    btAdapter.enable();




}


@Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2, long arg3) {

   //

    if (btAdapter.isDiscovering()){


        btAdapter.cancelDiscovery();

    }
    if (listAdapter.getItem(arg2).contains("Paired")){
              BluetoothDevice selectedDevice = devices.get(arg2);
        ConnectThread connect = new ConnectThread(selectedDevice);
        connect.start();


    }
    else{
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "device is not paired", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }


}

public void Discovery(View view) {

    startDiscovery();

}


             private class ConnectThread extends Thread {

    private final BluetoothSocket mmSocket;
    private final BluetoothDevice mmDevice;

    public ConnectThread(BluetoothDevice device) {
        // Use a temporary object that is later assigned to mmSocket,
        // because mmSocket is final
        BluetoothSocket tmp = null;
        mmDevice = device;
       // Log.i(tag, "construct");
        // Get a BluetoothSocket to connect with the given BluetoothDevice
     //  Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"client thread is working",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        try {
            // MY_UUID is the app's UUID string, also used by the server code
            tmp = device.createRfcommSocketToServiceRecord(MY_UUID);
        } catch (IOException e) {
          //  Log.i(tag, "get socket failed");


        }
        mmSocket = tmp;
    }

    public void run() {
        // Cancel discovery because it will slow down the connection
        btAdapter.cancelDiscovery();
        //Log.i(tag, "connect - run");
        try {
            // Connect the device through the socket. This will block
            // until it succeeds or throws an exception
            mmSocket.connect();
            Log.i(tag, "connect - succeeded");
        } catch (IOException connectException) {    //Log.i(tag, "connect failed");
            // Unable to connect; close the socket and get out
            try {
                mmSocket.close();
            } catch (IOException closeException) { }
            return;
        }

        // Do work to manage the connection (in a separate thread)

        //
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"reached the handler",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        mhandler.obtainMessage(SUCCESS_CONNECT, mmSocket).sendToTarget();
    }





    /** Will cancel an in-progress connection, and close the socket */
    public void cancel() {
        try {
            mmSocket.close();
        } catch (IOException e) { }
    }
}

          private class ConnectedThread extends Thread {
    private final BluetoothSocket mmSocket;
    private final InputStream mmInStream;
    private final OutputStream mmOutStream;

    public ConnectedThread(BluetoothSocket socket) {
        mmSocket = socket;
        InputStream tmpIn = null;
        OutputStream tmpOut = null;

        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Socket Thread is working",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        // Get the input and output streams, using temp objects because
        // member streams are final
        try {
            tmpIn = socket.getInputStream();
            tmpOut = socket.getOutputStream();
        } catch (IOException e) { }

        mmInStream = tmpIn;
        mmOutStream = tmpOut;
    }

    public void run() {
        byte[] buffer;  // buffer store for the stream
        int bytes; // bytes returned from read()

        // Keep listening to the InputStream until an exception occurs
        while (true) {
            try {
                // Read from the InputStream
                buffer = new byte[1024];
                bytes = mmInStream.read(buffer);
                // Send the obtained bytes to the UI activity
                mhandler.obtainMessage(MESSAGE_READ, bytes, -1, buffer)
                        .sendToTarget();

            } catch (IOException e) {
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    /* Call this from the main activity to send data to the remote device */
    public void write(byte[] bytes) {
        try {
            mmOutStream.write(bytes);
        } catch (IOException e) { }
    }

    /* Call this from the main activity to shutdown the connection */
    public void cancel() {
        try {
            mmSocket.close();
        } catch (IOException e) { }
    }
}
```

and this is the layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="leen.ibrahim.omar.bsapp.MainActivity">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:text="BLUETOOTH"
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Go"
        android:onClick="Discovery"
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

    <ListView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/listView"
        android:layout_below="@+id/button"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="47dp" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Enaple"
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView"
        android:onClick="TurnOn"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

this what appears in the logcat

> D/BluetoothUtils: isSocketAllowedBySecurityPolicy start : device null
>
> W/BluetoothAdapter: getBluetoothService() called with no
>   BluetoothManagerCallback
>
> D/BluetoothSocket: connect(), SocketState: INIT, mPfd:
>   {ParcelFileDescriptor: FileDescriptor[62]}

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your UUID in your client code is as same as the one in server code. The problem maybe because of your current UUID. You can get the UUID using the following in your server code:

```
TelephonyManager mTelephonyManager = (TelephonyManager) getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
String s_uuid = mTelephonyManager.getDeviceId();
UUID uuid = UUID.nameUUIDFromBytes(s_uuid.getBytes());
```

Don't forget the permission:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE"/>
```